# How do I accept an autocompletion suggestion using keyboard in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, hotkeys, autocomplete

I've just tried Windows 10 and found an awesome new feature: it can be configured to guess the words you type on a physical keyboard, pop the alternatives up and let you chose one. Much like the way it works on mobiles. This is extremely useful when you have to type in a foreign language you don't write really well.

However, having to pause your typing and use mouse to select an option feels annoying and limiting.

How do I select and accept an option using keyboard?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Up</kbd> to select the first text suggestion
2. Press <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> to switch between the different text suggestions
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to use the text suggestion of your choosing

[image]

Comment: To be honest, the direction keys may be as far as your mouse while typing. Going for an `Up` key and then `Enter` key is enough for me to complete this word with the keyboard.

Comment: I think a separate mouse will usually be a bit further away than the arrow keys on your keyboard, unless you're using a trackpad on your keyboard, in which case I agree that the trackpad would probably be a bit easier in that case.

Comment: I use my pinky for arrows. I have to use my whole hand to use the mouse, so it is way different and more convenient for me.  Though, the emoji completion is broken, you type a word that also matches an emoji, pick it using up and right arrows, it will insert the emoji but not replace the word (appends the emoji).  I am guessing but, it feels like they intended that. Developers have a bad habit of doing things the way THEY think it should work (or at M$, the way the boss' boss feels it should work).

Answer (score 0):

If I am using my keyboard, and a good autocomplete comes up, I press the End Key on the keyboard and then press enter. That certainly works in most instances.

Comment: The End key doesn't do anything with Windows 10's "Show text suggestions as I type". I think you're thinking of something else.

Comment: If I am typing and a single suggestion comes up, End completes it (for me). I do use this a lot in Windows 10.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you ever get multiple suggestions or just one? Do they look like the ones in my screenshot?

Comment: Yes, if I see multiple suggestions, then your method indeed does come into play.  I am then also more likely to use my mouse.  Thank you for your followup

Comment: Interesting. So I found a word that only produces one suggestion:"Microsoft". When I press End with just that one suggestion, Windows doesn't highlight it. In my testing, the only way to highlight even a single suggestion is to press Up. I'm baffled as to why End works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to configure accepting first suggestion using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Here is the code:

```
;Accept autocompletion first suggestion using keyboard
*CapsLock::Send("{Up}{Enter}")
```

This code instructions the keyboard to press <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> if I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. This mean it select the first suggested word.

You can map other key/combination of keys other than <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> if needed.